# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed' for RASA NLU supervised embeddings pipeline trainer

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, rasa-nlu, rasa

So I’m trying to train my data using **supervised embeddings** pipeline.

- Rasa version: **1.10.12**
- Tensorflow version: **2.1.1**
- Rasa NLU: **0.15.1**
- **config.yml** contains this:

> language: “en”
>
> pipeline: “supervised_embeddings”

I’m running this on a notebook, but I keep on getting an error about **tensorflow**:

```
 from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data

 from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig

 from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer 

 from rasa_nlu import config

 #Loading DataSet 

 train_data = load_data(my_data)

 #Config Backend: Supervised embeddings 

 trainer = Trainer(config.load('drive/Colab Notebooks/config.yml'))
 
 trainer.train(train_data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1a55633df253> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.train(train_data)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py in train(self, training_data, cfg, **kwargs)
    518             # set random seed
    519             np.random.seed(self.random_seed)
--> 520             tf.set_random_seed(self.random_seed)
    521 
    522             self.a_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, X.shape[-1]),

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'
```

From what I found on other forums about this error type, ***tf.set_random_seed(self._seed)*** needs to be moved to ***tf.random.set_seed()*** but in this case I can't access ***/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py*** and change it.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I used  **!pip install rasa==1.1.4**  instead of  **!pip install rasa**  since  ***supervised_embeddings***  pipeline has been deprecated on the newer versions of RASA.